# iisnode failed to process http response status line

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I'm using IISnode 0.1.21 x64 on Windows 2008 R2 and Node 0.8

My application is running successfully with 4 threads. But after sometime (say 3-4 hours) the responses don't make it from IISnode to the client and the user doesn't get the data on the page (but the rest of the application is working). I tried creating a log in the IISnode folder but didn't get anything from there.

If I remove even one node.exe process from the task manager, the application starts working properly. Then again after a couple of hours, i'm back to square one.

I got the ETW log and this is what it shows:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Guid="{1040dfc4-61db-484a-9530-584b2735f7f7}" />
        <EventID>0</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-21T13:21:56.783161800Z" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="2468" ThreadID="3484" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="195" UserTime="435" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer />
    </System>
        <Data>{00000000-0000-0000-6E02-0080000000CA}: iisnode failed to process http response status line</Data>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Guid="{1040dfc4-61db-484a-9530-584b2735f7f7}" />
        <EventID>0</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>5</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-10-21T13:21:56.783171500Z" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="2468" ThreadID="3484" ProcessorID="0" KernelTime="195" UserTime="435" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer />
    </System>
        <Data>{00000000-0000-0000-6E02-0080000000CA}: iisnode request processing failed for reasons unrecognized by iisnode</Data>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition oftentimes indicates that the connection between node.exe and iisnode was broken in the middle of the application sending back the HTTP response. This in turn may be a result of an exception during response processing. It might be a good idea to check your response code paths for unhandled exceptions, and/or register a global uncaughtException handler to see if any exceptions go unhandled. If that does not help, please open an issue at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/new.